# How to find a subnet mask

Tags: networking, subnet

Given a IP range as zz.yy+4.xx.0
Can anyone help me how to find a subnet mask for this?

I feel CIDR notation is missing.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to determine the subnet mask from an IP address alone.